# xpath query for editing a single sub-element with the same name and value that is contained in other elements

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm trying to update the value in one element (one by one) but I updated all that meet the condition of xpath. XML is not complex, for example:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <ELEMENT1>W</ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT2>IN</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>RP</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4>KKK</ELEMENT4>
  </row>
  <row>
    <ELEMENT1>2</ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT2>ARQ</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>MR</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4>AC</ELEMENT4>
  </row>
  <row>
     <ELEMENT1>3</ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT2>I</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>RP</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4>KKK</ELEMENT4>
  </row>
  <row>
    <ELEMENT1>1</ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT2>CC</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>XX</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4>I</ELEMENT4>
  </row>
  <row>
     <ELEMENT1>12</ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT2>IN</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>3</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4></ELEMENT4>
  </row>
</root>
```

All row elements have the same name (row), all row elements have the same elements with the same name and different values but can be repeated between the elements.
By java iterating I get the elements and if I want to update the value of ELEMENT4 of the third row using the following query XPath expression

```
/root/row/ELEMENT4[text()='KKK']
```

It change the value in all ELEMENT4 in all rows.If I tried something like this:

```
/root/row/ELEMENT3[text()='RP'][/root/row/[position()='3']]
```

The result is the same. What xpath query expression can I use to edit the value of a sub-element into an element without affecting the sub-elements with the same name from other elements?...very thanks

Comment: You probably need to provide a [NamespaceContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html) to map the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace. Example [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/java-using-xpath-with-namespaces-and.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `ELEMENT4` of the `3rd row` then just use :

`/root/row[3]/ELEMENT4`

you don't need to use the `text()` condition.

Comment: That XPath query was one of the first that I used but did not work, so far the only one that does something is:

/ Root / row / ELEMENT4 [text () = 'KKK']

but it changes all ELEMENT4 having the KKK value,
Thank you,

Comment: Which Xpath engine are you using?

I tested on http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath and it's working

Comment: javax.xml.parsers. *, javax.xml.transform. *, javax.xml.xpath. *, org.w3c.dom. * Java6 classes to transform XML DOM, manage files, and XPath queries. For other XML files with more complex queries I not had  problems, but with this simple XML no way

Comment: That's quite weird. What does the xpath `/root/row[3]/ELEMENT4` returns to you?

Comment: finally xpath query works fine, the problem was that the number of row position getting from iteration java and that number was not correct, I made a function to return the position of a child node within his parent and used that number to identify the position of each row…..../root/row[3]/ELEMENT4[text()='KKK']

Comment: I'll take a look into your new posts... meanwhile you may want to accept/upvote my answer if it's working for you. Thanks